# How to change order of callbacks in spring data jdbc?

Tags: java, callback, spring-data-jdbc

How to change order of callbacks in spring data jdbc? Primary, order, dependsOn used, didn't help.

```
@Bean
AfterDeleteCallback<? extends Document> test() {
    return (document) -> {
        log.info("test");
        return document;
    };
}

@Bean
AfterDeleteCallback<? extends Document> test1() {
    return (document) -> {
        log.info("test1");
        return document;
    };
}
```

Example with Order annotation:

```
@Bean
@Order(2)
AfterDeleteCallback<? extends Document> test() {
    return (document) -> {
        log.info("test");
        return document;
    };
}

@Bean
@Order(1)
AfterDeleteCallback<? extends Document> test1() {
    return (document) -> {
        log.info("test1");
        return document;
    };
}
```

logs:
[image]

And if I do the opposite (order(1) to test method and order(2) to test1 method, the result will be the same.

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
AfterDeleteCallback<? extends Document> test() {
    return (document) -> {
        log.info("test");
        return document;
    };
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
AfterDeleteCallback<? extends Document> test1() {
    return (document) -> {
        log.info("test1");
        return document;
    };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JDBC all extend the interface [`EntityCallback`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mapping/callback/EntityCallback.html) and its documentation actually describes how to order callbacks:

> Multiple entity callbacks are invoked sequentially with the result of the previous callback. Callbacks are unordered by default. It is possible to define the order in which listeners for a certain domain type are to be invoked. To do so, add Spring's common `@Order` annotation or implement `org.springframework.core.Ordered`.

You mention

> [..] order [..] used, didn't help

If this means you actually tried using the `@Order` annotation and it didn't work as intended, please post the code you used.
Of course, you should also try the alternative of implementing `Ordered`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added an example with an Order annotation to my question and logs in console. Could you take a look?